# Implementing auto increment column in Firebase web application

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a inventory application in which a unique auton-increment value needs to be generated for creating product ids.

Little confused how to generate a custom auto-increment id using firebase as back-end service.

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase Database equivalent of an auto-increment columns is called a *push ID*. These keys are generated when you call `push()` (or on iOS `childByAutoId`) and they are:

- guaranteed to be unique across all clients
- always increasing
- can even be determine while you're not connected to the server

But unlike the auto-increment columns in SQL databases:

- Firebase push IDs are strings, not numbers
- Firebase push IDs are not sequential

Instead of `1`, `2`, `3`, you'll get value like `"-KqB_B7Rh8cTYQxihbpb"`, `"-KqB_CfSXYZ3kp0a_WlT"`, `"-KqB_CuTwYXn-UtUEv0s"`. While they may be a bit harder to get used to, the advantages are well worth it.

I recommend reading more in these two blog posts:

- [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)
- [The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you insert data in Firebase, a unique id (UUID) is generated for object. The recommended practice is to use that [firebase-generated UUIDs](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) or a [custom UUID](https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11), but not an auto-increment id (Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065786/auto-increment-a-value-in-firebase-with-javascript))