# React Native + Firebase: Saving data with id increment

Tags: firebase, react-native

I would like to know if it's possible to save data into firebase and instead to get this kind of number as keys:

> KuL7a5iBOgrlvK9nMXJ

Insert this: 0,1,2,3,4 like MySql do.

Is that possible and how can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, `Firebase` does **not** support this behavior natively. You can, however, set your elements to whatever ID you like, so you could achieve this yourself.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39065899/7435814) and this [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) for further explanation.