# Firebase (web) giving index to each node

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

I am making program for hospital, every patient examination needs to have protocol number, who will increase for each examination, how can i make that part dynamic, for example i want to have like this in firebase index:'1/2018', next examination index:'2/2018'.

[image]

I am using angular 5 framework.
Ty.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Providing more details on what you're doing, what you've tried so far and which issue you're getting shall help to get answers for that.

Comment: @GCSDC i dont know from where to start. Is there way to connect all indexes in firebase so i can i++ every next input.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065786/auto-increment-a-value-in-firebase-with-javascript) may help