# how to generate auto increment id in fire-base real-time-database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to generate auto increment id to fire-base database. When the first item id must be 1 and second one must be 2.\

```
var database = firebase.database();
    var userDetails = database.ref("Article");

    userDetails.push({
        email: email,
        title: title,
        details: dis,

    });
```

Comment: I don't think Firebase supports auto-increment keys. Please refer to this post for a possible alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065786/auto-increment-a-value-in-firebase-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Firebase provides a real-time database. To do so, they provide offline features and also the ability to watch changes in the DB. As said in their [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write), they uses the best-effort approach, trying to keep data synchronized, but to keep your application responsive they write first locally and then synchronize the DB.

Using auto-increment id in this setting is problematic, because we may have two users adding stuff in their DB, which will happen locally, eventually one will be able to synchronize and the other will have a conflict. To avoid this, [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data) uses auto-generated keys based on timestamp and avoiding conflicts.

One important point is that these keys are ordered chronologically, which may be useful. Unless you have only one server doing all the operations (and not lot of apps or lot of user website sessions), it is better to deal with Firebase proposed paradigm, to avoid conflicts.