# How to check a missing number of all children in Firebase RealtimeDatabase?

Tags: python, java, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

So I was given a task to create a list of people who are registered through the app to give an ID with sequential number, for example the IDs would look like these: `PL0000001,PL0000002,PL0000003,PL0000004,PL0000005,PL0000006`

Easy to do it I thought, to create a new ID, just count children how many children there are in the members' section then + 1, then voila, new ID created.

But suddenly I realise, what if `PL0000003` then delete his account, then the new member's list will look like this: `PL0000001,PL0000002,PL0000004,PL0000005,PL0000006` and by using my algorithm, the code will just count the number of children, which is 5 now, + 1, which will become 6, but `PL0000006` is already exists. This will cause a double ID.

I have suggested them to use RealtimeDatabase's `.push()` function then take the `.key` as the members' ID. but they insist on having sequential number as the ID pattern.

If I read every single member's ID to check for a missing ID's number every time someone register, that will be expensive when there are thousands of members.

How can I check that `PL0000003` is missing in a cheaper solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to implement sequential counters like that is to store the last value that you handed out somewhere in the database.

If you do that, the steps to get the sequence number for a new node becomes:

1. Run a transaction on the sequence counter
2. Increment the value by one
3. Write the new sequence number for to the user node

Since you now have a transaction for the sequence counter and it only ever increases in value, there is no chance of two users getting the same sequence number.

Also see:

- [How to create auto incremented key in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519021/how-to-create-auto-incremented-key-in-firebase)
- [Auto increment a value in firebase with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065786/auto-increment-a-value-in-firebase-with-javascript)
- [Auto Increment in firebase real-time database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67868614/auto-increment-in-firebase-real-time-database)
- [How to get a "Sequence" or counters like structure in firebase realtime database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70025106/how-to-get-a-sequence-or-counters-like-structure-in-firebase-realtime-database)

Comment: Going with sequence numbers, though frequently something the "business" asks for, involves serialization of creation of those numbers.  Because of this serialization, it has an impact to the scalability of a solution.  I'm not suggesting this shouldn't be done, but I am suggesting that the business be pushed to provide a specific business reasoning for choosing a lesser-scalable approach.  This, BTW, is true of ANY system that supports "monotonically increasing values", not just Firestore.

Comment: Agreed Greg. ..